# SQL - Optimization Priority, Which of these apply?

Tags: sql, database

Products are made up of one or many components and components have individual price.

The cost of the product are calculated adding the cost of components used in that product.

Should I add a column named cost in Product table as they are not dynamic or Should I calculate everytime when a product is purchased?

Which one of these would be suitable approach in terms of speed, redundancy and performance?

I hope the scenario is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are absolutely sure the cost will never change, calculate it dynamically

Answer (score 2):

In my view, you should go with normal form unless you have EVIDENCE that there would be a performance issue with that approach. Yes, you would get better performance if you precomputed the bundled prices, but now you've added complexity in your data integrity validation. Is it worth it? Does computing prices dynamically slow down your response time to unacceptable levels? If you only have a few hundred products being served to a few dozen clients, then they wouldn't notice the difference.

There is a 3rd option that you may want to consider. If your database platform supports indexed views, you can create a view that returns a computed column for product price, that would give you the speed of the denormalized approach without the data integrity risk.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers so far really seem to address the issue.  Price is generally a slowly changing dimension.  That means that the same price for a component can be different at different points of time.  When bringing up slowly changing dimensions, I usually recommend Ralph Kimball's book "The Data Warehouse Toolkit", whatever the latest edition is.

In other words, you should have an `EffDate` and `EndDate` for the prices in your `PriceList` table.  That way, you know what the price is at any point in time.

In addition to the price for the components at any given point in time, you should also track the price of components within a product.  You can handle this with a `ProductComponent` association/junction table.  This would have columns such as:

- ProductId
- ComponentId
- Currency (if appropriate)
- Discount (as pointed out by Jonathan)
- Tax
- Full Price
- Net Price

The full price would come from the `PriceList` table.  I know that "Full Price" is now redundant with the `ProductComponent` table, but it is amazing how useful this bit of redundancy can be.

Then, you would simply use this table to bring together the cost for any given product at any given time.  You can readily calculate the price for any product using the `ProductComponent` table.

Comment: I think the idea of adding effdate and enddate to your component pricing has merit. But I'm confused about the ProductComponent table schema listed above. Why would you reference tax in this table as this would change based on the jurisdiction? Nor does it vary based on component (I assume).

Comment: @Aheho . . . The `PriceComponent` would represent the pricing for a component at a given point in time.

Comment: I don't think tax belongs in that table, and you didn't list effectivedate or EndDate.

Comment: @Aheho . . . They are two different tables.  The `Price` table should have an effective and end date and a full price.  The use of the price table at any given point in time (say when a product is sold or produced) would have the junction table that would include tax, discounts, and other information specific at that point in time.

Comment: So you are not tracking the changes in component pricing over time, you are only tracking price changes at the product (aggregate) level. Do I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `PriceList` table, that has the ProductId and a price.

Comment: Why? Most decisions to go beyond 3NF should have a rationale.

Comment: because rarely do you have a single price, you also have a history of your price.  pretty simple, most CRM systems all have price lists for this exact reason.

Comment: Then you need at least another column to pick the right one. And, in my view, a more descriptive table name. Otherwise, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this the other way round: 
Each thing that has a price of its own, is a stock keeping unit (or sku).
Each individual sku is a product.
You can then group things up into 'product groups','bundles' or 'packages'. 
For pricing, its a difficult one: I usually use an extra database table, e.g.:

```
id | bundle_id | sku_id | discount
1    1           1        0
2    1           2        50%
3    2           3        0
4    3           4        10%
```

Then calculate the 'bundle price' dynamically (this allows the bundle price to be less than the sum of the components, or even more than the sum of the components with a -ve discount)

It also means that the bundle prices go up and down automatically as the sku prices change.
You can go further by automatically making the price rounded to the nearest $0.99 (but that would have to be agreed with your client first).